# Can't access specific element using parent and child jquery methods

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access .sub-menu element and all its contents on the hovered anchor rom the most outer children. Here in the code below this would be the Sports link.

I've tried using a couple of methods as below on console.log to access it

```
var $desktopMenu = $('.desktop-menu');

$desktopMenu.on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().html());             // <a href="" > Menu Item</a>
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().html());    // all html inside 'desktop-menu 
    console.log($(this).next().html());               // undefined
    console.log($(this).parents('.sub-menu').html());               // undefined
    console.log($(this).find('.sub-menu').html());               // undefined
});
```

HTML

```
<ul class="desktop-menu">
   <li class=""><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
   <li class="sub-menu">
      <div class="container">
          <ul>
             <li class="heading"><a href="#">Running</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Footwear</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
```

I'm consfused as to why the parent() methods arent working as expected. Surely the parent() of this  will be li and parent().parent() would be the next  not desktop-menu ul? Any ideas why this is? thanks

EDIT: Added two of the suggestions below to things i've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way : [.find()](http://jqapi.com/#p=find)

```
$desktopMenu.on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
    console.log($(this).parent().parent().find('.sub-menu').html());      
      // .submenu inside the anchor hovered
});
```

Comment: This too creates a log of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents('.sub-menu')` function which opposed to `parent()` goes more than one level up the DOM tree
js:

```
var $desktopMenu = $('.desktop-menu');

$desktopMenu.on('mouseenter', 'a', function(){
 console.log($(this).parents('.sub-menu').html());
});
```

html:

```
<ul class="desktop-menu">
   <li class=""><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
   <li class="sub-menu">
      <div class="container">
          <ul>
             <li class="heading"><a href="#">Running</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Footwear</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: This creates a log of undefined

Comment: Thanks lvil, it does work when you hover over running. But im wanting when you hover over Sports. Sorry I should have been clearer will update question.